# Redux-Form getting warning for: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to use **redux-form** in my React app. Its working fine generally, but I am getting a warning in strict mode :

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

class IssuesNew extends Component {
  renderTitleField(field) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input {...field.input} type="text" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Link to="/">Go to all Issues</Link>
        <h1>Create a new issue</h1>
        <form><Field name="title" component={this.renderTitleField} /></form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'IssuesNewForm',
})(IssuesNew);
```

Here is my stack versions:

```js
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux-form": "^8.3.6",
```

I saw that there is a comment about this but with no answer: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/3954#issuecomment-522813906

Is there any way to fix this or make it go away?

Comment: I think the best way to solve this would be solving it in redux-form. Issue looks like it needs someone to take care of (provide a PR).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to go with redux-form and not [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#-react-final-form)? If not, I would recommend it based on the [author's comment](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form#%EF%B8%8F-attention-%EF%B8%8F) on redux-form github page. 

**In short**: final-form supersedes redux-form and is recommended unless you "need really tight coupling of your form data with Redux"

Comment: @PieterBuys hmm.. I am working on an existing application which is using it. I am trying to update it. I will look into react-final-form more indepth. Thank you!